# CreateIconFromResource return NULL and UI crashed after being called thousands of times

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Anybody got this problem, anyway I didn't find an answer. The code is simple:

```
void CbDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        HRSRC hRes = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME), RT_GROUP_ICON);
        HGLOBAL hResLoad = ::LoadResource(NULL, hRes);
        BYTE* pIconBytes = (BYTE*)::LockResource(hResLoad);
        int nId = ::LookupIconIdFromDirectory(pIconBytes, TRUE);
        hRes = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nId), RT_ICON);
        DWORD read = ::SizeofResource(NULL ,hRes);
        hResLoad = ::LoadResource(NULL, hRes);
        pIconBytes = (BYTE*)::LockResource(hResLoad);
        if(pIconBytes != NULL)
        {
            HICON hIcon = ::CreateIconFromResource(pIconBytes, read, TRUE, 0x00030000);
            DWORD e = ::GetLastError();
            if(hIcon != NULL)
            {
                ::DestroyIcon(hIcon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the Ok button four times (On my computer), CreateIconFromResource start to return NULL (It worked fine before and I could even draw out the icon). As to the GetLastError, it's always return 6 whatever CreateIconFromResource return NULL or not.

When this problem happened, if I drag the title bar to move, UI crashed, see the pictrue.
[image: UI crash]

Of course you can understand this piece of code is just a demo, my real business need to call CreateIconFromResource thousands of times just like this.

UPDATE:
According to Hans' suggestion, I keep tracking the Handles/USER Objects/GDI objects, and found that USER Objects grows 1000 and GDI objects grows 2000 against each clicking to OK button (handles didn't grow), and GDI objects is 9999 when problem happens. But how to release them correctly, when I finish to use? I didn't use that much at one time, but need to load, release, load again, release again... Just like this demo. As MSDN document, I called DestroyIcon for every HICON. What else do I need to do, to finally release the USER/GDI objects?

Comment: You are probably leaking handles, the show is over when you leaked 10,000 of them.

Comment: @Hans, thank you, by your suggestion, I found it's USER/GDI objects leaked, but I still have question, as updated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The success or failure is all due to MSDN.

It says:

"*The CreateIconFromResource function calls CreateIconFromResourceEx passing LR_DEFAULTSIZE|LR_SHARED as flags*"    AND     "*Do not use this function(DestroyIcon) to destroy a shared icon*"

But It also says:

"*When you are finished using the icon, destroy it using the DestroyIcon function*" in CreateIconFromResource's document.

Actually, the second statement is WRONG.

So, the solution is, using CreateIconFromResourceEx without LR_SHARED, and DestroyIcon every HICON after using.